# Querying Ef context using LinqPad: Argument Exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linqpad

I have added Ef connection in linqpad like following[image]
As you can see connection is successfully added but when i want to query against this connection i get the following exception

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

it seems to be connected with connection string but how it would be solved, i have no idea. The context is defined in asp.net mvc project (no separate project for data access) and connection string is in web.Config file as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, I was able to solve it by following the instructions here

1) Find the path that LINQPad uses for its configuration file by excuting this: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile.Dump()

> This returned for me the following: C:\Program Files\LINQPad4\LINQPad.config
>
> 1. I was suprised this returned LINQPad.config instead of LINQPad.exe.config 
>      which is what you would typically expect since most .NET applications name the > file the same as the executable.
> 2. Take your App.config and copy it to the location above naming the config 
>      file whatever yours returned. In my case it was LINQPad.config
> 3. Close LINQPad or the TAB that you have opened to execute your assembly and reopen to get LINQPad to read the configuration file.

http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2012/06/01/Getting-LINQPad-to-read-your-applications-AppConfig-settings.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of LINQPad support direct connections to projects with a DbContext or ObjectContext.  With that connection type, you can specify your app.config / web.config when setting up the connection.

http://www.kevinlabranche.com/blog/ConnectingLinqPadToEntityFrameworkCodeFirst.aspx